# iPhone: A simple PDF Viewer with saving functionality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I would like to find a simple PDF Viewer with downloading functionality.

I have tried a couple of examples but they are not for ios5, so giving me errors.
Would you give me some suggestions which one i could use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple PDF Viewer would be a `UIWebView`.
First download the PDF using `NSURLConnection` and it's matching delegates, then after completion show the webview